# Update made in MySQL database does not reflect on the webpage

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I updated contents of my website on its corresponding MySQL database, through phpMyAdmin. The changes are showing in the database however it does not reflect on the webpage.

What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `commit` to save the changes.

More info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to configuration page and Check for the database connectivity first. Sometimes this can also be responsible for not reflecting the changes.